# How to do batched writes as part of a transaction

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I found myself in a situation where I want to perform some operations on the database that should be handled in a single transaction. One of those operations is injecting > 500 documents, so this is throwing an error because it's hitting

> maximum 500 writes allowed per request

In order to work around that, you could use batched writes, but I can't figure out how to do batched writes as part of a transaction. It seems like `transaction.commit()` is not a thing and in the docs transactions and batched writes appear to be two separate concepts.

Comment: Both batches and transactions are subject to the 500 document cap.  They are both essentially trying to "commit" a number of documents.  The difference is that transactions are first trying to read the documents first in order to make changes to existing contents, whereas batch writes are just writing.  Transactions only work online, because they require a connection with the server, but batch writes can work offline, because they just contain a list of deltas to apply, regardless of existing contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, we are using transactions to have consistent data. The recommendation that you get:

> you could use batched writes

It is for the exact same reason. Unfortunately, you cannot mix them. You have to choose one or the other. Realistic speaking, both the batch and the transaction are used for atomic updates.

A transaction is similar to batch and as the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) states:

> All of the operations succeed, or none of them are applied.

The main difference between a batch write and a transaction is that a batch just writes, while a transaction reads and right after then writes.

So the solution in your case is to use [Firestore batched-writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to perform 500 operation at a time.

Comment: Thanks Alex. That seems like the solution. It is only write-operations that are relevant in my case. They are spanning two different collections, but that's not a problem for batched writes.

Comment: O, maybe not... "All of the operations succeed, or none of them are applied." only goes for one single batch. I have 500+ documents and so I will need to commit multiple batches. If one fails I have no way to revert the commits from the previous batches.

Seems like this is just not possible with the current Firestore API.

Comment: Yes, it only goes with a single batch. If you have more than 500 documents, you should create your own mechanism for that. And that's right, I can confirm that there is also no mechanism to revert a previous batch.

Comment: I'll accept the answer. It wasn't a solution for me, but there currently is none apparently.

Answer (score 0):

As you have most probably read in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction):

> The `Transaction` object passed to a transaction's updateFunction
>   provides the methods to read and write data within the transaction
>   context.

and this object, in the Client SDKs, has only four methods: `get()`, `set()`, `update()` and `delete()` which all take a single Firestore Document as parameter.

With the [Node.js Server SDK for Google Cloud Firestore](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/index.html), you will note that there is an additional method, `getAll()`, which "retrieves multiple documents from Firestore. Holds a pessimistic lock on all returned documents".

---

So, at the time of writing, there is no possibility, to "mix" a Transaction and a Batched Write.